# Stretching div to height of parent

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I understand that some variation on this question has been asked many times.

However, I can't seem to get this to work using the recommended methods.

Why is the `flex: 1` seemingly being ignored?

The aim is for the red container to fill the available space below it.

CodeSandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2w3nwxoppr).

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import styled, { createGlobalStyle, ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";

const Style = createGlobalStyle`
  body, html {
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
`;

const FlexCol = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header>header</Header>
      <FlexCol>{children}</FlexCol>
    </div>
  );
};

const Header = styled.div`
  height: 50;
  background: blue;
`;

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Feed />
    </div>
  );
};

const FeedContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
`;

const Feed = () => <FeedContainer>something</FeedContainer>;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Home />
    </Layout>
  );
};

render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={{}}>
    <React.Fragment>
      <Style />
      <App />
    </React.Fragment>
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[image]

Comment: you missed `height: 100%;` on the first div ... well a lot of them are missing, you made only the body to be 100% and none of their child

Comment: Which div do you mean? If you mean the Layout one, adding that doesn't seem to change it.

Comment: you only set the body to be 100% and none of its child. You have the root div and inside it another div

Comment: Would you mind editing the CodeSandbox example to show what you mean?

Comment: I don't know react, so I cannot help you ... I simply comment based on the generated code I see

Comment: Okay, well adding `height: 100%` to everything doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: not to everything, but you should follow the structure and the flexbox container where you have your blue and red div should be height:100% of the screen and then flex:1 will work on the red div. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/9tznufma/ .. but you have many nested div and it's confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this can also be achieved by styling the `Layout` and using `flexGrow` where relevant.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import styled, { createGlobalStyle, ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";

const Style = createGlobalStyle`
  body, html {
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
`;

const FlexCol = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
`;

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "100vh", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <Header>header</Header>
      <FlexCol>{children}</FlexCol>
    </div>
  );
};

const Header = styled.div`
  height: 50;
  background: blue;
`;

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "100%"
      }}
    >
      <Feed />
    </div>
  );
};

const FeedContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
`;

const Feed = () => <FeedContainer>something</FeedContainer>;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Home />
    </Layout>
  );
};

render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={{}}>
    <React.Fragment>
      <Style />
      <App />
    </React.Fragment>
  </ThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What's missing in your setup is the height on intermediate container between body and the layout. The container in which you are rendering your react app: #root.

Adding 100% height on it fixes the problem:

```
const Style = createGlobalStyle`
  body, html {
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  #root { //<-- this thingie
    height: 100%;
  }
`;
```

Here's an updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xrw84wkw54

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with the React Router BrowserRouter messing up my styles, but it's essentially the same as your answer, so I'll mark it as correct. Thank you! For future people: be careful `BrowserRouter` is not squashing your styles.

Comment: Can you comment on the difference between putting `height: 100%;` on the `#root` tag, versus making the `Layout` div `height: 100vh`? Is one preferable to the other?